# setting the same value for multiple swift parameters

Tags: swift, function, swift2

I have a function similar to this:

```
func stamp(documentURL: NSURL, saveURL: NSURL) {
        ...}
```

I'd like to be able to allow someone to set both of those parameters if they want. But if they only set the first parameter, I'd like saveURL = documentURL. Is there any way to do this in the function declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this in the function declaration itself, however you can do it in a single line of the function body by using an optional parameter with a default of `nil`, and the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72).

```
func stamp(documentURL: NSURL, saveURL: NSURL? = nil) {
    let saveURL = saveURL ?? documentURL

    // ...
}
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that `saveURL` is non-optional within the function body, saving you from having to use the force unwrap operator later.

Answer (score 3):

**In Swift 2.3, 3:**

```
func stamp(documentURL: NSURL, saveURL: NSURL?) {
     var saveURL = saveURL
     if saveURL == nil {
         saveURL = documentURL
     } 
}
```

Comment: It applies to Swift 2.3 too.

Comment: I guess there's no way to do this in the function declaration without code in the body?

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 2**

```
func stamp(documentURL: NSURL, var saveURL: NSURL? = nil) {
    if saveURL == nil {
        saveURL = documentURL
    } 
}
```

**SWIFT 3**

```
func stamp(documentURL: NSURL, saveURL: NSURL? = nil) {
    var saveURL = saveURL
    if saveURL == nil {
        saveURL = documentURL
    } 
}
```

Comment: Using `var` is discouraged in Swift functions as it will be removed in Swift 3. Just create a local variable with the same name.

Comment: @ozgur thanks I updated adding the swift 3 safe version

Comment: So, I guess there's no way to do in the function declaration?

Comment: @TomJ No, there is not